# How to use generics to compare the size of two types

Tags: ios

I want to define a method to compare stuff such as `int` or `double` etc, using Generics. But I'm having this error:

> Binary operator '>' cannot be applied to two 'T' operands.

Here's my code, how can I make it work?

```
func test<T:Numeric>(a: T,b:T)-> T{
    return a > b ? a : b
}
```

I have solved by:

```
 func test<T:Comparable>(a: T, b: T)-> T {
    return a > b ? a : b
}
```

Comment: Please post your question in English so we can help you. Looking at your code, though, your types are all mixed up. `a > b` is a `Bool`, but `a`, `b`, and `T` are `Numeric`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `>` operator requires conformance to `Comparable`

```
func test<T : Comparable>(a: T, b: T) -> T {
    return a > b ? a : b
}
```

However the function already exists in the Swift Standard Library and is called [max](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1538951-max)

Comment: Thank you for your answer，I already know how to do it through your answer